# Regex - list the characters which are not matching the pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have below regex which says if the given input matches the pattern or not

```
String input="The input here @$%/";
String pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9,.\\s]*";
if (!input.matches(pattern)) {
System.out.println("not matched");
}else{
  System.out.println("matched");
}
```

Can i know how it can be enhanced to list the characters in the input, which are not matching the pattern. E.g here `@$%/`

Comment: Please let me know , what clarity is need, so that i can provide the required information

Comment: Thank you every one those you helped to reopen the question and eventually to get the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [anubhava has already mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753522/regex-list-the-characters-which-are-not-matching-the-pattern/66753992#comment118000948_66753522), just use `input.replaceAll(pattern, "")`.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "The input here @$%/";
        String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9,.\\s]*";
        String nonMatching = input.replaceAll(pattern, "");
        System.out.println(nonMatching);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
@$%/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9,.\s]
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/xeQv2X/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
 [^a-zA-Z0-9,.\s]         any character except: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z', '0' to '9', ',', '.', whitespace (\n,
                           \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

**[Java code snippet](https://tio.run/##dVDfS8MwEH7PX3EMhRRs3KuUgj7sURDmk9uEs41tujQNyXVOZX97zdZMytB7yAd39/24NLjDtCm3w6Ba2zmCJjRET0oLJyu5F49IRS1dxv6ZPyGRdCZjrNDoPSz22Fot4ZtBKNu/aVWAJ6QAu06V0KIyfElOmWq1AXSVT@Lysd6VQQ3jGE4OkMNs9Yrp10P6Mk/vbsR67Tez7G@GHyFQnmsJytieIKSXcH91fRtIF6wYHmzE/NwRRddapSU/RUgu3eKnhFtGzM8KInb4GCSZOH7UQQ94XBBBqOTJ9PRjLT89yVZ0PQkbBEibX0Llut7yeTIJc2DjexiGHw)**:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,.\\s]";
        final String string = "The input here @$%/";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i know how to handle ^ "The input here @$%/^";

Comment: @upog Do you want to keep it? If it must stay use `String regex = "[^^a-zA-Z0-9,.\\s]"`