# Regular expression to find everything except a pattern

Tags: java, regex, ansi-escape

I'm pretty new to regular expressions and am looking for one that matches anything except all that matches a given regex. I've found ways to find anything except a specific string, but I need it to not match a regex. Also it has to work in Java.

Background: I am working with Ansi-colored strings. I want to take a string that has some text that may be formatted with Ansi color codes and remove anything except those color codes. This should give me the current color formatting for any character appended onto the string.

A formatted string may look like this:

```
Hello \u001b[31;44mWorld\u001b[0m!
```

which would display as `Hello World!` where the World would be colored red on a blue background.

My regex to find the codes is

```
\u001b\[\d+(;\d+)*m
```

Now I want a regex that matches everything but the color codes, so it matches

**Hello** \u001b[31;44m **World** \u001b[0m **!**

Comment: Use your regex in `replaceAll` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - list the characters which are not matching the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66753522/10819573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello \u001b[31;44mWorld\u001b[0m!";
    String result = Pattern.compile("\u001b\\[\\d+(;\\d+)*m").matcher(input).replaceAll("");
    System.out.println("Output: '" + result + "'");
}
```

Output:

```
Output: 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't really meant to give 'everything but' the regex match. The easiest way to generally do something like this though is match what you want (like the color codes in your case), then take the string you have, and remove the matches you found, this will leave 'everything but' the match.

Quick sample (very untested)

```
String everythingBut = "string that has regex matches".replaceAll("r[eg]+x ", "");
```

Should result in `string that has matches` i.e. the inverse of your regex

Comment: I thought of that as well, but what do I do with it? I cannot use it as regex to remove all of it from the initial string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  It simply finds all the matches and puts them in an array which can be joined to a String if desired.

```
String pat = "\u001b\\[\\d+(;\\d+)*m";
String html = "Hello \u001b[31;44mWorld\u001b[0m!";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(html);
String[] s =  m.results().map(mr->mr.group()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text="Hello \u001b[31;44mWorld\u001b[0m!";
Arrays.asList( text.split("\\[([;0-9]+)m"))
.stream()
.forEach(s -> aa.replaceAll(s,""));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[31;44m[0m
```